# How to search all articles belongs to a tag in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

### Article Model

```
class Article {
    public function Tag(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

### Tag Model

```
class Tag {
    public function Article(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

### Pivot Table

```
article_id === tag_id
```

I want to search all books use a tag's name. How can I do this?

### My Solution

```
public function tagArticle($name)
{
    $tags = $this->tag->where('name',$name)->get();
    $articles = [];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $articles[] = $tag->articles;
    }
    return view('front.home')->with('articles',$articles);
}
```

> This is my solution, but I don't think it's good. Does anyone has other solutions? Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned `Article` & `Tag`, but you want to search `books` using tag, and your codes showing you are getting `posts` with `tag`, so what is the relationship of these 4 entities?

Comment: I have edited the question.There are three tables,article,tag,and article_tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `whereHas()`

```
 $articles=Article::whereHas('tags',function($query)
        {
            $query->where('name',$name);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with `flatten` would be better.

```
$tags = $this->tag->where('name',$name)->get();

$articles = $tags->map(function($v) { 
    return $v->articles; 
})
->flatten()
->all();
```

The flatten will return all articles in the same level

```
[
   articleObject,
   articleObject,
   articleObject,
]
```

More detail https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map